# Include library like jQuery only if needed and used in somewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something is in my mind but don't know how to implement it. Is it really implementable?

jQuery is not included in whole website. When it is used in some files, it will return an error that `$` or `jQuery` is not defined and here is what I want to do. I want to make something like `try/catch` in a `app.js/root.js/parent.js/index.js (or any other file.js that is accessible from other js files or we can call it the parent of other js files)` in order to get all `throw`s and if the type of the throw (which is thrown from a child) is related to `jQuery` or `$` then include `jQuery` in the file that had called it. Is it possible?

child.js

```
$(document).html('test');
```

It is not defined so that, it throws an `undefined` error.

and here (that I don't know how) to catch the error

index.js (app.js / root.js / parent.js and any file that is accessible by any other js file)

```
if(typeof error == 'jquery not defined') {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
}
```

and then the `window.$` should be returned to the caller in order to use it.

Thank you :)

Comment: Yes this is possible, but it's redundant. If the error has already occurred then adding the jQuery.js library in the page at that point is too late. Why not just add jQuery (and all required libraries) in every page? Make sure they're minified and bundled and you'll reduce loading speed, and from the first load they will be cached for all future requests. Changing the scripts on every page most likely slows the site down as a whole.

Comment: One option: Rename all your .js files that use jquery to ..-jq.js (eg index-jq.js) the when you add `<script src=index-jq.js` you can immediately see that you have to add `<script src="jquery.js"` before it.  (though I personally would go with above comment to include it on every page - modern browsers cache the parsed file, so if it's the same file every time, there would be zero impact after the first time on the first page (and none if using a CDN that the user's already visited on another site))

Comment: `If the error has already occurred then adding the jQuery.js library in the page at that point is too late.` Yes, but I thought it could send the jquery instance in order to be used by the caller. Can't this be accessible afterwards by returning the instance in some ways? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Good idea but it is on existing project that has many js files. @freedomn-m

Comment: Potentially, yes, but would be a massively overcomplicated solution to a problem which can already be solved more efficiently.